# Selecting items in CSV file using Date

Tags: powershell, csv

I am trying to select items by date in a CSV file using PowerShell.  The format in the CSV file for the date is `1/8/2018  10:04:00 AM`.  When I run this I get no data although I know that data exists.

```
$events = Import-Csv c:\normtest\server2_perf.csv | foreach {
  New-Object PSObject -prop @{
    Date    = [DateTime]::Parse($_.Date);
    CPULoad = $_.CPULoad;
    MemLoad = $_.Memload
  }
}
$events | Where { $_.Date -eq (Get-Date).AddDays(-4) }
```

Comment: Do you get results without the where clause?

Comment: `{$_.Date -eq (get-date).AddDays(-4) }` - > `{$_.Date.Date -eq (get-date).Date.AddDays(-4) }`

Answer (score 0):

As you have a time part to your date, this will only work for **exactly** 4 days from now (i.e. where time of day = right now).

Assuming this part works correctly: `Date = [DateTime]::Parse($_.Date);`, you can do this:

```
$start = (Get-Date).Date.AddDays(4)
$fin   = $start.AddDays(1)  # assuming 1 day window

$events |
    Where {$_.Date -gt $start -and  $_.Date -lt $fin}
```

Alternatively, you could treat the date field as string:

```
$events = Import-Csv c:\normtest\server2_perf.csv |
              Where {$_.Date -like "$(Get-Date).AddDays(-4).ToString("M/d/yyyy"))*" }
```

Assuming your date format is `"M/d/yyyy"`

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Thanks!